# Symfony 4 manytoone relation allow adding in a form builder

Tags: symfony

I have a manytoone relationship between a subscription entity and a customer entity.
I am making the form to add a subscription to a customer.
In this form I can select an already existing customer but I would like to be able to create a new customer if it does not exist.

### CustomerEntity :

```
class Customer implements \JsonSerializable
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=180, unique=true)
     */
    private $name;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): void
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function jsonSerialize(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __toString(): string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
```

### SubscriptionEntity :

```
class Subscription
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Customer")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $customerName;  

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @return CustomerName
     */
    public function getCustomerName()
    {
        return $this->customerName;
    }

    public function setCustomerName($customerName): self
    {
        $this->customerName = $customerName;

        return $this;
    }

    public function __toString()
    {
        return $this->customerName;
    }
}
```

### SubscriptionType (form) :

```
class SubscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
         ->add('customerName', null, array(
             'required' => true,
         ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TicketSubscription::class,
            'customerName' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```

So currently I can create a subscription for an existing customer, I would like to know how I can do to create a subscription for a non-existing customer?

Comment: I find it confusing, that you have a property called "customerName" which is a customer entity (and not just the name). why is it called that way? regarding your problem: it's not that simple to do both (selecting, creating) in one form. instead of `->add('customerName', null, ...)` you could `->add('customerName', CustomerType::class, ...)` and also add a `CustomerType` for specifying the Customer properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refers to this official doc for complete implementation: https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html
You have to use CollectionType to contains the collection of the customer in your case. Then, in your twig, write some jquery to dynamically add a new customer.
Something like:

```
class SubscriptionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
         ->add('customers', CollectionType::class, array(
             'entry_type' => CustomerType::class,
             'entry_options' => [
                'allow_add' => true,
                'prototype' => true
             ]
         ));

    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => TicketSubscription::class,
            'customerName' => null
        ]);
    }
}
```